# How does one create an ASM LdcInsnNode that statically adds the current class to the stack?

Tags: java, java-bytecode-asm, bytecode-manipulation, jvm-bytecode

I'm using the [ASM library](http://asm.ow2.org/) to modify bytecode created by others. For an arbitrary method in an arbitrary class, I'd like to create an `LdcInsnNode` that adds the current class to the stack.

For example, let's say I'm transforming a class called `com.example.ExampleClass`. I'd like to create bytecode that is equivalent to `System.out.println(ExampleClass.class.getName());`.

This seems like a relatively simple task. When I use the Eclipse Bytecode Outline plugin, it says that the following bytecode is equivalent:

```
GETSTATIC java/lang/System.out : Ljava/io/PrintStream;
LDC Lcom/example/ExampleClass;.class
INVOKEVIRTUAL java/lang/Class.getName ()Ljava/lang/String;
INVOKEVIRTUAL java/io/PrintStream.println (Ljava/lang/Object;)V
```

I tried the following code:

```
private InsnList printClass() {
    InsnList result = new InsnList();
    result.add(new FieldInsnNode(Opcodes.GETSTATIC, "java/lang/System", "out", "Ljava/io/PrintStream;"));
    result.add(new LdcInsnNode("L" + name + ";.class"));
    result.add(new MethodInsnNode(Opcodes.INVOKEVIRTUAL, "java/lang/Class", "getName", "()Ljava/lang/String;", false));
    result.add(new MethodInsnNode(Opcodes.INVOKEVIRTUAL, "java/io/PrintStream", "println", "(Ljava/lang/String;)V", false));
    return result;
}
```

This is being run in an extension of `ClassNode`, so `name` refers to the `ClassNode.name` field. The `InsnList` returned by this method is being inserted before an existing `AbstractInsnNode` using `InsnList.insertBefore(AbstractInsnNode, printClass())`. When this point is reached in the bytecode, I get an error with the following reason:

```
Type 'java/lang/String' (current frame, stack[1]) is not assignable to 'java/lang/Class'
```

This is clearly because the LDC instruction is adding the String `"Lcom/example/ExampleClass;.class"` instead of the actual class `Lcom/example/ExampleClass;.class`.

Is there any workaround for this? It seems impossible to directly add the `Class` object to an `LdcInsnNode` because the class doesn't exist yet. But is there a way to add an instruction that loads the `Class` object?

In my particular case, calling the `Object.getClass()` method is not an option because it needs to work from a static context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don’t need to refer to a `Class` object, in fact, it isn’t even supported (directly). If you want to push a `Class` to the operand stack via ASM, you have to refer to it as [`Type`](http://asm.ow2.org/asm50/javadoc/user/?org/objectweb/asm/Type.html) instance.

E.g.

```
new LdcInsnNode(Type.getObjectType(name))
```

using the [`Type.getObjectType(…)`](http://asm.ow2.org/asm50/javadoc/user/org/objectweb/asm/Type.html#getObjectType-java.lang.String-) factory method, which expects `name` to represent the internal name form, e.g. `com/example/ExampleClass` without `L … ;` around it. It’s equivalent to `Type.getType('L'+name+';')` for non-array types. The choice of the factory method is important as a `Type` object may represent primitive types or method types as well. Since both, `ldc` and `Type.getObjectType`, only support reference types, this is the natural combination.

It seems the [`LdcInsnNode` constructor documentation](http://asm.ow2.org/asm50/javadoc/user/org/objectweb/asm/tree/LdcInsnNode.html#LdcInsnNode-java.lang.Object-) is a bit outdated, as it only mentions number types and `String` (`Class` support with `ldc` exists since Java 5, but the documentation contains links to 1.4.2). You may refer to [`MethodVisitor.visitLdcInsn(…)`](http://asm.ow2.org/asm50/javadoc/user/org/objectweb/asm/MethodVisitor.html#visitLdcInsn-java.lang.Object-) instead, to which the object is eventually passed when producing the byte code.